# taxonomy cck pathauto

Tags: taxonomy-terms, path-aliases

Can anyone tell me how to set the taxonomy in the following order

1. super Category---eg(Area)
2. Category--- eg(food)
3. sub category --- eg(fruits)

if a visitor chooses a super category area, then the fruits in that area should be shown
 And the path should be http://www.example.com/supercategory/category/subcategory/apple.php

Comment: You don't seem to be asking your question coherently.  If a vistor chooses a super category, shouldn't it show what foods (category) are available there, not what fruits (subcategory)? In any case, you need to investigate the menu() hook and all of its %wildcards.

Comment: thanks, Actually my need is exactly like for example, in ecommerce site when a visitor changes the country, the price and the products are changed. likewise, in my suituation when a visitor chooses a area, the product and prices will be changed.

Comment: i am sorry, you are right, when a visitor chooses a super category,then we should show the category and then the fruits...

Comment: I agree with jimajamma. You question is rather incoherent in it's current state. From it, I get two questions. 1. How do I set up Conditional Display of taxonomy lineage for users to select? 2. How do I set pathauto to use the taxonomy lineage in the URL structure?

Comment: also, you do not specify whether you are using D6 or D7?

Comment: You cant set path like that. You need to specify various vocabulary to gain such a path.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're asking more than one question, but let me try and address the paths one. If you organise your taxonomy to be hierarchical then using the token [catpath-raw] will give you the path you require.